# javascript [argument: type] mean?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I notice react-native **UIExplorer - ListViewGridLayoutExample** use some strange syntax which I actually never see it.

```
_pressData: ({}: {[key: number]: boolean}),

// some code ...

_genRows: function(pressData: {[key: number]: boolean}): Array<string> {
  var dataBlob = [];
  for (var ii = 0; ii < 100; ii++) {
    var pressedText = pressData[ii] ? ' (X)' : '';
    dataBlob.push('Cell ' + ii + pressedText);
  }
  return dataBlob;
},
```

how to understand `_pressData`? is that object? and what about `_genRows` method arguments?

Comment: Looks like some sort of static type checking. Not sure about what it is, but that's definitely not regular JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment at the beginning of the file contains a `@flow` directive which means the file is using http://flowtype.org/ for static type checking.

From the website

> What is Flow?
>
> Flow is a static type checker, designed to find type errors in JavaScript programs

See also the `.flowconfig` file in the root of the project.

To understand what `_pressData` is check out http://flowtype.org/docs/objects.html especially the section at the bottom "Objects as Maps".

`_pressData: ({}: {[key: number]: boolean}),`

the first part `{}` is simply an object literal. Without flow the equivalent would simply be

`_pressData: {},`

the second part `{[key: number]: boolean}` defines the type of keys and values this map accepts (this notation means we use the object as a map). Namely numerical keys with boolean values, e.g. `{2: false, 19: true}`.